# Replace src path in script tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I m doing api call and in the response of that call I m getting HTML data.
That HTML data has some script and css files to load and path of that file is coming like
this

`<script src="/v2/resources.js" defer=""></script>`

It is fetching data from my localhost, so basically it is hitting localhost/v2/resources.js to get script file , now I want to change to it some other host., How can I do that?

Comment: `<script src="https://otherhost/v2/resources.js" defer=""></script>`

Comment: i have whole html code in response of API call , how to change in that?

Comment: You need to modify HTML data in order to do it. How do you get that data. Is it a string?, a JSON object? I guess you can use the `replace()` function to search the `script` tag and modify the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by doing this (see comments):

```
// Parse the HTML -- this will _not_ run the scripts
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(theHTMLFromTheAPI, "text/html");

// Loop through the `script` elements that have `src`
for (const script of doc.querySelectorAll("script[src]")) {
    // Append a new script element with an updated src
    const newScript = document.createElement("script");
    // Note using `getAttribute`, not the reflected `src` property,
    // to get the source URL so that it isn't calculated relative to the
    // document for us. The URL constructor lets us specify a base URL
    // (https://example.com in this case) that will be used to resolve the
    // relative URL
    newScript.src = new URL(script.getAttribute("src"), "https://example.com");
    // This will run the script from the updated URL:
    document.documentElement.appendChild(newScript);
}
```

References:

- [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)
- [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)
- [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)